# cp_menu_array hook : nav_ not getting picked up

Tags: control-panel, hook

I am hooking in to cp_menu_array - which seems light on the old documentation - to stick up a menu for my module.

All works as expected, except the language strings.

```
public function cp_menu($menu)
{
    if ($this->ee->extensions->last_call !== false) {
        $menu = $this->ee->extensions->last_call;
    }       

    $menu['giftcards'] = array();
    $menu['giftcards']['view_giftcards'] = BASE.'&amp;C=addons_modules&amp;M=show_module_cp&amp;module=store_giftcard';
    $menu['giftcards']['edit_giftcard_emails'] = BASE.'&amp;C=addons_modules&amp;M=show_module_cp&amp;module=store_giftcard';

    return $menu;
}
```

This gives me the required menu item, but the strings pop up as 'nav_giftcards', etc.  So, one might expect to stick them in the lang array thus:

```
$lang = array(
    "store_giftcard_module_name" => 'Store Giftcard',
    "store_giftcard_module_description" => 'Gift certificate functionality     for Expresso Store',
    "nav_giftcards" => 'Giftcards',
    "nav_view_giftcards" => 'View Giftcards',
    "nav_edit_giftcard_emails" => 'View Giftcards'
);
```

Alas, to no avail.

If anyone can point out the trick I'm probably missing before I need to dive in and walk through the core to find out, I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add next lines into your cp_menu_array code in case if you need to have some dynamic code:

```
ee()->lang->language['nav_giftcards'] = 'Giftcards';
ee()->lang->language['nav_view_giftcards'] = 'View Giftcards';
ee()->lang->language['nav_edit_giftcard_emails'] = 'View Giftcardss';
```

Or load your file with lang array:

```
ee()->lang->loadfile($module_name);
```

Comment: Thanks for that Max - both suggestions work, though the first negates internationalisation, so I'll roll with the second for now.  If this turns out to be only solution, though, it's a PITA hack to cover a shortfall of EE, given the core adds the nav_ prefix without documenting the behaviour, and then fails to handle it.